# Query speed of insert/ update SMA (simple moving average)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, query-optimization

I would like to include a column in my table with the simple moving average of stock data. I have been able to create several queries which successfully do so, however the query speed is slow. My goal is to improve the query speed.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `timeseries_test` (
 `timeseries_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `stock_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `open` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `high` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `low` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `close` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `adjusted_close` double(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `volume` int(16) NOT NULL,
 `dividend` double(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `split_coefficient` double(16,15) NOT NULL,
 `100sma` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`timeseries_id`),
 KEY `stock` (`stock_id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 KEY `date_stock` (`stock_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5444325 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have tried many different query formats, but they all take about 25 seconds per 5000 rows. The select query only takes less than a second. Below an example query:

```
UPDATE stock.timeseries_test t1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT a.timeseries_id,
       Round( ( SELECT SUM(b.close) / COUNT(b.close)
                FROM timeseries_test AS b
                WHERE DATEDIFF(a.date, b.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 99 AND a.stock_id = b.stock_id
              ), 2 ) AS '100sma'
     FROM timeseries_test AS a) t2

ON t1.`timeseries_id` = t2.`timeseries_id`
SET t1.100sma = t2.100SMA
WHERE t2.100sma = null
```

Below the explain query:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10385   10.00   Using where 
1   UPDATE  t1  NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   t2.timeseries_id    1   100.00  NULL    
2   DERIVED a   NULL    index   NULL    date_stock  7   NULL    10385   100.00  Using index 
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  b   NULL    ref stock,date_stock    stock   4   stock.a.stock_id    5192    100.00  Using where
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, I recommend window functions with a `range` specification; this avois the need for a correlated subquery.

```
update stock.timeseries_test t1 
inner join (
    select timeseries_id,
    avg(close) over(
        partition by stock_id 
        order by date 
        range between interval 99 day preceding and current row
    ) `100sma`
    from timeseries_test
) t2 on t1.timeseries_id = t2.timeseries_id
set t1.`100sma` = t2.`100sma`
```

It is quite unclear what the purpose of the original, outer `where` clause is, so I removed it:

```
WHERE t2.`100sma` = null
```

If you do want to check for `null`ness, then you need `is null`; but doing so would pretty much defeat whole logic of the `update` statement. Maybe you meant:

```
WHERE t1.`100sma` is null
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I am running MySQL 5.7.2, however. If I do not find an alternative solution I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not sargable.  Instead of

```
DATEDIFF(a.date, b.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 99
```

use

```
a.date BETWEEN b.date AND b.date + INTERVAL 99 DAY
```

(or maybe `a` and `b` should be swapped)

I suspect (from the column names) that the pair (`stock_id`,`date`) is unique and that `timeseries_id` is never really used.  If those are correct, then

```
PRIMARY KEY (`timeseries_id`),
KEY `date_stock` (`stock_id`,`date`)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY(`stock_id`,`date`)
```

The `ON(timestamp_id` would need to be changed to testing both those columns.

Also, toss this since there is another index that starts with the same column(s):

```
KEY `stock` (`stock_id`),
```